# Как сделать пробелы в CSV там, где нет данных?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, csv

Есть JSON файл, который выглядит так:

```
{"q":"1",
"w":[{"aa": "111","ab":"222","ac":"333"},
     {"aa": "444","ab":"555","ac":"666"},
     {"ad": "777", "ae": "888", "af": "999", "ag": "000", "ah": "123"],
     {"aa": "234","ab":"345","ac":"456"}}
```

Всего 8 ключей. У меня CSV заполняется так:

```
111,222,333
444,555,666
777,888,999,000,123
234,345,456
```

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы в БД записывалось правильно:

```
111,222,333,,
444,555,666,,
,,,777,888,999,000,123
234,345,456,,
```

У меня есть конгфиг файл. Можно ли его тут применить или изменить под задачу?

```
[KEYS]
aa = 'aa'
ab = 'ab'
ac = 'ac'
ad = 'ad'
ae = 'ae'
af = 'af'
ag = 'ag'
ah = 'ah'
```

Код считывает каждую строчку из JSON и эту строчку толкает в CSV, то есть он не видит все заголовки JSON и поэтому он заполняет CSV так, как заполняет. Я потому и спросил, поможет ли мне конфиг, чтобы указать парсеру на все заголовки JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если у нас есть словарь с данными:

```
In [8]: data
Out[8]:
{'q': '1',
 'w': [{'aa': '111', 'ab': '222', 'ac': '333'},
  {'aa': '444', 'ab': '555', 'ac': '666'},
  {'ad': '777', 'ae': '888', 'af': '999', 'ag': '000', 'ah': '123'},
  {'aa': '234', 'ab': '345', 'ac': '456'}]}
```

можно воспользоваться модулем Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(data["w"]).to_csv(r"c:/temp/result.csv", index=False)
```

---

Результат:

```
aa,ab,ac,ad,ae,af,ag,ah
111,222,333,,,,,
444,555,666,,,,,
,,,777,888,999,000,123
234,345,456,,,,,
```

Comment: тащить огромную библиотеку, ради того чтобы просто сохранить данные в csv? Так себе идея :/

Comment: @Basalex, насколько мне известно автор хочет заливать эти данные в БД. В Pandas это делается одной строкой: `df.to_sql("tab_name", alchemy_connection)` Как думаете сколько кода понадобиться, чтобы сделать это без этой "огромной библиотеки"? ;)

Comment: @MaxU, спасибо, я как раз тут думал о пандас. Вы уже запомнили меня? :D

Comment: @MaxU,  две строки кода?
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.executemany("""INSERT INTO table(col1, col2, col3, ..) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, ...)""", data)

Comment: @Basalex, теперь надо добавить возможность заливать кусками (chunks), и коммитить куски. Кроме этого, для того чтобы прочитать все данные в `data` вам понядобится еще один цикл и несколько дополнительных строк кода. После этого автору наверняка захочется обрабатывать, анализировать и визуализировать данные. В Pandas это делается очень легко и элегантно

Comment: @MaxU,  чанки - это еще пару строк кода, не вижу в этом никакой проблемы, данные из data он не будет читать в таком случае, а будет делать запрос в БД с нужными параметрами. Что касается анализа данных и прочего, то если у автора до этого момента не было  pandas, очевидно там другая история и в принципе не правильно ставить какую то библиотеку, просто потому что она возможно понадобится. В данном конкретном случае использовать pandas - это все равно что стрелять из пушки по воробьям.

Answer (score 1):

Из коробки все ровно так и должно работать:

```
  import csv

  headers = ('aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'ae', 'af', 'ag', 'ah')
  rows = [{"aa": "111","ab":"222","ac":"333"},
       {"aa": "444","ab":"555","ac":"666"},
       {"ad": "777", "ae": "888", "af": "999", "ag": "000", "ah": "123"},
       {"aa": "234","ab":"345","ac":"456"}]

  with open('d.csv', 'w') as f:
      w = csv.DictWriter(f, headers)
      w.writeheader()
      w.writerows(rows)
```

Output:

```
aa,ab,ac,ad,ae,af,ag,ah
111,222,333,,,,,
444,555,666,,,,,
,,,777,888,999,000,123
234,345,456,,,,,
```

Comment: `
for tr in result:
    if count == 0:
        header = tr.keys()

(некоторые манипуляции с данными)

csvwriter.writerow(tr.values())
`
С каждой итерацией получается:
`
dict_keys([aa,ab,ac])
dict_keys([aa,ab,ac])
dict_keys([aa,ab,ac])
dict_keys([ad,ae,af,ag,ah])
dict_keys([aa,ab,ac])
`
И заполняется неправильно

Comment: @Demoralization, думаю стоит выложить весь код, хотя мне уже не понятно зачем делать хедеры в цикле, их достаточно сделать один раз - максимально полные

Comment: Я бы с радостью, но мне нельзя. Да и в принципе там ничего полезного не найдете. Можете уточняющие вопросы задавать

Comment: Да по идее хидеры можно не писать в самом csv. Я убрал их сейчас из кода

Comment: Код считывает каждую строчку из json и эту строчку толкает в csv, то есть он не видит все хидеры json и поэтому он заполняет csv так, как заполняет. Я потому и спросил, поможет ли мне конфиг, чтобы указать парсеру на все хидеры json.

Answer (score 0):

```
for tr in result:
    if count == 0:
        header = tr.keys()
        print(header)
(некоторые манипуляции с данными)

csvwriter.writerow(tr.values())
```

С каждой итерацией получается:

```
dict_keys([aa,ab,ac])

dict_keys([aa,ab,ac])

dict_keys([aa,ab,ac])

dict_keys([ad,ae,af,ag,ah])

dict_keys([aa,ab,ac])
```

И заполняется неправильно

Comment: не нужно передавать values в writerow, прям целиком словарь нужно отдавать (tr в данном случае), если csvwriter - это конечно csv.DictWriter(f, headers) -  как в моем ответе

Comment: @Basalex, csvwriter.writerow(tr)? Так все равно не получается

Comment: проверил локально - работает как раз как нужно

Comment: @Basalex, я кажется понял свою ошибку, проверю и отпишусь